# col-sm inside a div with margin on one side

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm new to web design and I've been looking for an answer for this and can't find it.

So I want to add a fixed vertical navbar to the side of my page, so I wrapped my whole page with #everything and added a left margin of 50 px, just so there's enough space to make the bar. However, when I do this, the text doesn't fit to the width of its parent. It seems it resizes according to the page size, not to size of its container.

What can I do so the text doesn't overflow, instead, it adapts to the size of its container?

```css
#everything{
margin-left:50px;
}
```

```html
        <div id='everything'>   

        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
              <p>text long enough to make a paragraph</p>
              <p>text long enough to make a paragraph</p>
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
              <p>text long enough to make a paragraph</p>
              <p>text long enough to make a paragraph</p>         
            </div>
          </div>
       
       </div>
```

So I'm starting to use bootstrap and have made this so I have responsive paragraphs on my page.
I want to add a fixed navbar to the side of my page, so I wrapped the whole page with a #all id

Comment: adding your code snippet would be best to solve your issue.

Comment: "*It seems it resizes according to the page size, not to size of its container.*" ... `#everything` doesn't have a defined width so it's the same width as the page.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something you are looking for

```css
#bar {
  width: 50px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div id="bar">
    aaaa
  </div>
  <div id='everything'>   

    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <p>text long enough to make a paragraph</p>
        <p>text long enough to make a paragraph</p>
      </div>
      <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <p>text long enough to make a paragraph</p>
        <p>text long enough to make a paragraph</p>         
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  
</div>
```